# Why don't Etron USB 3.0 controllers/ports work? (Asus P8Z68-V and other motherboards)

Tags: usb

I have a new computer with an Asus p8z68-v le + Intel 2500 + 8GB of RAM.

I installed Ubuntu without any issue but the USB3 (from the mother board - on the back of the computer) don't work.

I plug a USB stick noting, I plug my USB3 external drive nothing, but when I plug them in the USB2 everything works perfectly.

I ran all updates also and everything is up to date.  What am I missing?

Comment: Apparently you're not the only one with this problem. I searched with "ubuntu 11.10 usb 3 not working asus p8z68" which didn't provide any solutions, only people with the problem. There is potential for cockpit problems, the USB 3 ports on the mobo are blue and the USB 2 ports are red.

Answer (score 3):

The Asus manuals for z68 based mobo have been updated to explicitly state that USB3 depends upon Windows (post boot) software.  Running Ubuntu you will not get M/B raid support, (out of the box) USB3, or SSD shadowing of highly used sectors. (Intel Smart Response).

I can understand not including a raid controller, but USB3 should just work. It's a serious consumer issue in my Country if the product description misleads in this way.

You'll need another motherboard, or an expansion card.

Comment: yea after looking at the manual It says that it Is Windows Only, I always respected Asus for their products being reliable, now they lost a bit of respect from me for less support for a better OS. Now, don't suppose anyone knows a way to trick or force USB 3.0 functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I found a package available that may help assist in activating the driver for the 3.0 device. You can simply run

```
sudo apt-get install libccid
```

After it installs, I suggest a reboot and then try and see if it works.

Also, I had found out that indeed the driver for it,

Gigabyte GA-990FXA-UD3 (rev. 1.1) Etron USB 3.0 driver 105 linux is already supported in the Linux kernel, as of the most recent build around January 2012.

It may be that if your 3.0 device is not being read and your laptop is very new, then further implementation of a kernel with support for such a new driver is most likely in the works, but just not been released yet, but could be very soon.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem with my Asus U46E RAL 7.  The USB 3.0 external HD is not being recognized at boot time.  I searched web and found one solution:  add the word `usb_storage` into `/etc/modules`.  Then the drive is recognized at boot time.

Comment: By the way, Windows 7 still refuses to see my USB3.0 external HD at boot time.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1680278):

> ```
> gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
> ```
>
> Change
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nomsi"
> ```
>
> Save the file and enter:
>
> ```
> sudo update-grub
> ```
>
> Reboot the system. The USB 3 ports should be working now.

---

See also: [nomsi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Signaled_Interrupts).